# PHP secure logon script - md5 hash is not matching the hash i wrote to the database in a previous script?

Tags: php, md5, salt, login-script

I am trying to cobble together a login script in PHP as a learning project.

This is the code for my database write when the user registers. Both of these values are written to the database.

```
 $this->salt = md5(uniqid());
 $this->password = md5($password.$salt);
```

Upon logging in, the following function is fired.

```
function challengeLogin($submittedPassword, $publicSalt, $storedPassword){
    if(md5($submittedPassword.$publicSalt) == $actualPassword){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return 1;
    };
}
```

Unfortunately, on stepping through my code, the two values have never equaled. Can someone help me understand why?

Comment: $publicSalt is the user's salt from the database, correct? The one generated by `$this->salt = md5(uniqid());` when creating an md5 of the password?

Comment: And the difference between $storedPassword and $actualPassword in the second block is just a typo?

Comment: And returning `0` (`false`) when the two match is a typo as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem in your code is that the `$salt` variable is undefined, so it is empty. You should use `$this->salt`

Change

```
$this->password = md5($password.$salt);
```

to

```
$this->password = md5($password.$this->salt);
```

Comment: You're probably exactly right. This sort of stumble is exactly why I decided to take an object oriented approach. I'm comfortable with scripting, but functional and OO programming... not so much.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the raw values before it gets hashed with some basic echo statements. Either the salt is wrong, your password is wrong, or the hash somehow got screwed up.